# Giving permission to your ASP.NET Application to a Directory in a File Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a Web Server xxx.xxx.xxx.26 (let's call it **.26**), and it has an application using **'DefaultAppPool'** as the Application Pool.

In that ASP.Net application there is supposed to be a capability of opening a file by using **Process.Start()** (I use C# btw)

```
string path = @"\\10.132.142.27\one_test\Advisory.msg"; 
Process.Start(path);
```

This works fine if I'm debugging or using localhost, but when it's publish in .26, the application says "Access denied" or "no network provider accepted the given network path". I googled every possible solutions but no luck so far. I already have given access to the User of the application in full control.

Specs:
Web Server: Server 2003 IIS is version 6,
VS2013 Framework 4
File Server: Server 2003/2012

What should I do to open the file? Please help! :'(

Comment: did you try full path?

Comment: You need to grant permissions to the account that the app pool is running under.

Comment: I think you need to give IUSR and IIS_IUSRS Group permissions to the directory.

Comment: Please confirm that the pages are running as 'anonymous'.  Also, could you please post the code that opens the files.  Your "Process.Start()" syntax above, only sounds like you are doing *some undisclosed actions* on a separate thread.  It would help to know what kind of actions (read or write or delete or executing, etc)

Comment: `string path = @"\\10.132.142.27\one_test\Advisory.msg";
                    Process.Start(path); ` @tgolisch
above is the code i used in the Process.Start()

Comment: @Dan
I seem can't find the IUSR or IIS_IUSRS in the group permission of any locations in the directory

Comment: @itsme86
I really don't know what my account in the app pool is and how to give permission to it.